# Access the value of another function after window.location in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So here is my `content.js` file.

```
var title
function content(e) {
    title = e.getAttribute('title');
    // alert(title); //it alerts the title 
    window.document.location="movie";
}

function setcontent(){
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = title; //undefined
}
```

The `content(e)` function is called by `recommend.html` and after it redirects to the page `movie.html`,  `setcontent()` function will be called by the `movie.html`.

Here is my `movie.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Movie Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='content.js')}}"></script>
</head>

<body onload="setcontent()">
    <center>
        <div id="name"></div>
    </center>
</body>
```

But once the browser redirects to `movie.html`, it shows `undefined` in the place of id `name` instead of the title value. I'm not sure what went wrong. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: To hold data on page change you need to either pass it via a query string or use localStorage (I would recommend that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data between page loads, then you need to store it in the browsers "localStorage" (or "sessionStorage"). Like this:

```
function content(e) {
  localStorage.setItem('title', e.getAttribute('title'));
  window.document.location="movie";
}

function setcontent(){
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('title');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect, window object will belong to new window. Your previous window's variables won't be available in new window.

You can achieve your use case by:

```
var title
function content(e) {
    title = e.getAttribute('title');
    // alert(title); //it alerts the title
    window.document.location=`movie?name=${title}`;
}

function setcontent(){
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = window.location.search.split("=")[1];;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript program (in the context of a `<script>` element) runs *inside a web page*.

If you navigate to a new webpage then you are effectively quitting that program and running a new one.

Variables don't have a life-span longer than the program they are part of.

---

If you want data from one page to be available in another then the first page needs to put it somewhere that the second page can access.

Such places include:

- the URL
- local storage
- a cookie